# Find the basis for the range of linear transformation From $M_{22} \mapsto M_{22}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$T: M_{22} \mapsto M_{22}$ defined by:

$T(A) = AB$ where B = $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

So AB = $\begin{bmatrix}
        a-b & b-a \\
        c-d & d-c \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

after multiplying arbitrary matrix A by matrix B. My question is, what would be the basis for the range of this transformation? I have found the kernel and $dim(ker(T)) = nullity(T) = 2$, so I know the $rank(T) = 2$ but i'm really struggling to find the basis for the range here.

If someone could help me out here I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: From the rank-nullity theorem, it seems like I should have 2 elements in the basis for the range. Although that is helpful as well thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a basis for the range, just apply the transformation to basis elements of your domain.

In this case, using the standard basis, we find that $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
Which give a basis (note that the other basis vectors give us multiples of these, so we are finished).

Comment: @MichaelLee I'm not sure exactly what you mean - $T(A)$ is defined to be $AB$, so finding $T$ is the same as right-multiplying by $B$.

Comment: Oh, whoops, I misread the question.

Comment: ok I was really confused, but this makes sense. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $A=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right]$ we have
\begin{align*}
T(A)
&= BA \\
&= \left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{rr}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right] \\
&= \left[\begin{array}{rr}
a - b & -a + b \\
c - d & -c + d
\end{array}\right] \\
&= 
a\cdot\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
+b\cdot\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
+c\cdot\left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right]
+d\cdot \left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right] \\
&= (a-b)\cdot\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]+(c-d)\cdot\left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
This shows that 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{image}{image}\image(T)=
\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\left\{\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right]\right\}
$$
Showing that $\left\{\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right]\right\}$ is linearly independent is simple.